# Python syntax error with If/Else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

hey I need help with a stupid syntax error using the if and else statement.

```
     GNU nano 2.2.6                      
#!/usr/bin/python

print 'ACTIVATED'

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN) ## Setup GPIO Pin 40 to OUT
GPIO.input(40) ## Turn on GPIO pin 40
for x in xrange(10):
  if: GPIO.input(40)
print ('CHEESE')
  else:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

heres the error:

```
File "./gid.py", line 12
if: GPIO.input(40)
  ^
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? `if` what?

Comment: Colon goes after the condition, not after `if`.

Comment: @xnx i will eventually want it to take a picture with raspistill but for now its not even beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` needs to have a conditional

```
if: GPIO.input(40) # wrong placing of semicolon with missing conditional
```

it has to be

```
if GPIO.input(40): # correct usage
```

as `GPIO.input(40)` returns a boolean

(Apart from that your `print` indent has mismatched)

Comment: put your question in a different fourm

Comment: I down voted before your edit.  You suggested "if True: GPIO.input(40)" at first which was clearly not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Trent Thanks. I wanted to just tell the OP that you have to put something there. After others felt the same as u, I edited the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean `if GPIO.input(40):`.  The colon goes after the entire `if` condition.

Comment: now i get 
ACTIVATED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gid.py", line 11, in <module>
    if GPIO.input(40): # correct usage
RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel first

Comment: your code has a error (above)

Comment: @GideonMorrow: That error has nothing to do with the syntax of the `if` statement, but something to do with whatever `GPIO` is.  I don't know what `GPIO` is, but your question (and your error) was about Python syntax.  If you have a question about how that GPIO object works you should ask that separately.

Comment: useless... gpio is a General Purpose outlet to a rpi

Comment: and i reached my "asking limit"

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong:

`if: GPIO.input(40)` should be `if GPIO.input(40):`

You need to define something to happen inside the if statement.  For example:

```
if GPIO.input(40):
    print('CHEESE')
```